# Spring Security Not Working After Upgrading to 3.2.0.RC2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I just upgraded from Spring Security 3.2.0.RC1 to 3.2.0.RC2. Everything worked fine under RC1. Under RC2, my custom login page no longer works. The login page is just redislayed after clicking the Login button. If invalid credentials (or no credentials) are submitted, it also redisplays without any error message. Before it would correctly display an error message if the credentials were incorrect.

What is interesting is if I change from:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off

    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/restricted/**").hasRole("admin"))
            // all requests must be authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/myLoginUrl.request")
            .failureUrl("/myLoginUrl.request?error")
            .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/myLoginUrl.request")
    ;
    // @formatter:on
}
```

to:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off

    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/restricted/**").hasRole("admin"))
            // all requests must be authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/myLoginUrl.request")
    ;
    // @formatter:on
}
```

The default Spring Security login page is displayed and works. I've looked at the source of the default page and compared it to my custom page and it seems to call the same action with fields with the same names.

If I step through the debugger, I find that in AntPathMatcher.java,  public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request):

```
String url = getRequestPath(request)
```

The url returned is "/error" when using my custom login page. getRequestPath() just returns request.getServletPath() appended to request.getPathInfo(). I'm not sure why upgrading to RC2 would cause this to return "/error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three things that I changed that made this work.

1) Added a CSRF hidden field to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

2) Capitalized POST for the form method:

```
<form action="login" method="POST">
```

3) Explicitly added loginProcessingUrl to the configuration:

```
.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/myLoginUrl.request")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .failureUrl("/myLoginUrl.request?error")
        .permitAll()
```

Comment: There should be no need to use POST over post. What was happening if you used post and what browser were you using? The loginPage("/login") states that GET /login be the login form. Additionally, unless explicitly set it will update the defaults for logout success to /login?logout login error to /login?error and POST /login be the login processing URL.

Comment: You are correct. I've switched back to a lowercase 'post' and it still works. 

I think that the '/error' may have been caused by the lack of the CSRF token. Was that a change between RC1 and RC2? I didn't need it before.

Tested with latest Chrome, IE 8, and latest Firefox. Everything works.

Thanks for your work on this, @Robb Winch. Best security solution I've seen. The Javaconfig is super nice.

Comment: You should have needed the CSRF token for log in with RC1 unless you had it disabled using http.csrf().disabled(). If you use Spring MVC's tag lib or Thymeleaf 2.1+ the CSRF token is automatically included on forms.